# Como se faz para exibir o "Pressione ENTER para continuar" em Python 3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu queria saber como se faz o " *Pressione ENTER para continuar*", ou o "*Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar*" em Python 3.4, sem ter que criar uma variável só para armazenar o ENTER.

Comment: Outra coisa: não qu evocê tenah que criar uam variável para isso - mas é errado você se preocupar com "ter que criar uma variável a mais para fazer X" 0- não há custo perceptível com a criaçãod e vairáveis (no caso de Python e outras linguagens dinâmicas, nem o custo de declarar a variável) -- por outro lado se você programar pensando em não criar variáveis, vai acabar criando código mais dificil de ler e de manter.

Comment: jsbueno, na verdade é porque tinha que apertar ENTER duas vezes, e eu queria que só tivesse que apertar só uma. Aí imaginei que o problema era que os dois ENTERs eram o seguinte: Um para ser a variável e o outro, para dar o resultado para a variável. Então pensei em fazer sem a variável e perguntei aqui.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basta não guardar o resultado do input em uma variável

```
input("Pressione ENTER para continuar")
```

Comment: Não sabia que o input() podia ser usado sem uma variável.

Comment: O `input()` é uma chamada de função como qualquer outra. Você pode atribuir o valor retornado pra uma variável ou simplesmente ignorálo. Você também pode passar o valor direto pra uma outra função: `faz_coisa(input())`

Comment: Assim como o Mateus Souza, eu também não sabia dessa.

Answer (score 5):

Para exigir o <kbd>Enter</kbd> (i.e. ignorar tudo o que o usuário digitar até que o <kbd>Enter</kbd> seja pressionado), ver a [resposta do hugomg](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69853/215). Já no caso de aceitar qualquer tecla (i.e. retornar o que quer que o usuário tenha digitado, sem esperar pelo <kbd>Enter</kbd>) [essa pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/510357/520779) mostra uma implementação do `getch` em Python. Uma de suas versões é:

```
def _find_getch():
    try:
        import termios
    except ImportError:
        # Non-POSIX. Return msvcrt's (Windows') getch.
        import msvcrt
        return msvcrt.getch

    # POSIX system. Create and return a getch that manipulates the tty.
    import sys, tty
    def _getch():
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(fd)
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
        return ch

    return _getch

getch = _find_getch()
```

Ao utilizar, você pode ignorar o valor de retorno se quiser, porém é necessário imprimir a mensagem inicial separadamente:

```
def anykey(msg='Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar'):
    print(msg)
    getch()
```

Answer (score 0):

Vamos tentar fazer isso finalizando o processo atual e mostrando a mensagem "Pressione alguma tecla para continuar . . ." nativa do sistema:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call([r"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", "/c PAUSE"])
```

vai executar o comando `pause` nativo do MS-DOS, mostrando com a linguagem baseada no sistema.

Answer (score -1):

Para encerrar o programa basta adaptar o código para algo parecido com:

```
while True:

    sair = str( input( '\nPRESSIONE "ENTER" PARA SAIR ' ) )

    if not sair:

        exit()
```

Answer (score -4):

```
from os import system, name

# definir função de pause pra win, mac ou Linux

def pause():
  # para linux e mac são exatamente o mesmo comando.   
  if name == 'linux':
    os.system("""bash -c 'read -s -n 1 -p "Press any key to continue..."'""")

  #windows
  else:
    _ - system('C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe','/c PAUSE')
```