# Como sair de um loop com hotkeys

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tenho uma aplicação que roda em background num loop infinito.
Como faço para parar o loop usando *hotkeys* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>~<kbd>F12</kbd>)?

Comment: O que você já fez?

Comment: Já pensou em usar *multithreading*? Postei abaixo respondendo literalmente ao que foi perguntado, mas não tenho certeza se essa é a melhor maneira de se fazer isso.

Comment: @MaiconCarraro estou fazendo uma versão melhorada [disso](https://github.com/Fnandoz/AutoClick/blob/master/PyAutoClick.py), restando apenas, parar o programa.

Comment: @mgibsonbr vou estudar sobre multithreading. Grato

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, é preciso um meio de se detectar que o usuário está tentando pressionar uma tecla sem de fato ler essa tecla (do contrário, o loop ia parar e ficar esperando a entrada do usuário). De acordo com [essa pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/292095/520779), isso é feito através do módulo [`select`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html) ou - como a função relevante não é suportada no Windows - [`msvcrt.kbhit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.kbhit).

## Windows

Um exemplo no Windows seria:

```
>>> indice = 0
>>> while not msvcrt.kbhit() and indice < 1000000:
...   indice = indice + 1
...
_
```

(o cursor fica piscando, mas o loop continua executando, até o usuário digitar qualquer tecla)

```
>>> indice
401247
```

Quanto a detectar *hotkeys*, o que eu percebi nos meus testes (não sei se é a melhor forma de fazer) é que se você tentar ler a entrada do usuário usando [`msvcrt.getch`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.getch) (ainda no Windows) após uma sequência dessas, ele vai dar `\x00` (F1 a F10) ou `\xe0` (F11 e F12):

```
>>> msvcrt.getch()
'\x00'
```

E se você tentar ler *de novo*, então ele vai gerar um segundo caractere, dependendo da sequência digitada:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

```
>>> msvcrt.getch()
'\x00'
>>> msvcrt.getch()
'^'
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>

```
>>> msvcrt.getch()
'\x00'
>>> msvcrt.getch()
'g'
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

```
>>> msvcrt.getch()
'\xe0'
>>> msvcrt.getch()
'\x8a'
```

Etc

```
F1      F2      F3      F4      F5      F6
'\x00^' '\x00_' '\x00`' '\x00a' '\x00b' '\x00c'

F7      F8      F9      F10     F11        F12
'\x00d' '\x00e' '\x00f' '\x00g' '\xe0\x89' '\xe0\x8a'
```

O código completo seria então:

```
while True:
    # Faz alguma coisa

    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        a = msvcrt.getch()
        b = msvcrt.getch() if msvcrt.kbhit() else None
        if a == '\x00' and b == '^': # Ctrl + F1
            break
```

## POSIX

No Linux (e presumivelmente também no Mac) a solução envolve `select` para fazer *polling* do teclado, e `termios` para obter as teclas pressionadas (como detalhado [nessa minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69870/215) a uma pergunta relacionada):

```
>>> import sys, tty, termios, select
>>> def getch():
...   fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
...   old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
...   try:
...     tty.setraw(fd)
...     ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
...   finally:
...     termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
...   return ch
... 
>>> def kbhit():
...   fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
...   old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
...   try:
...     tty.setraw(fd)
...     i,o,e = select.select([sys.stdin],[],[],0.0001)
...     for s in i:
...       if s == sys.stdin:
...         return True
...     return False
...   finally:
...     termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
... 
>>> while True:
...   # Faz alguma coisa
...   if kbhit():
...     if getch() == '\x1b':
...       a, b, c, d = getch(), getch(), getch(), getch()
...       if a == '[' and b == '1' and c == '1' and d == '~': # Ctrl + F1
...         break
... 
>>>
```

Nos meus testes ele gerou 5 caracteres, o primeiro sempre `\x1b` e os 4 seguintes dessa forma:

```
F1:  [ 1 1 ~
F2:  [ 1 2 ~
F3:  [ 1 3 ~
F4:  [ 1 4 ~
F5:  [ 1 5 ~
F6:  [ 1 7 ~
F7:  [ 1 8 ~
F8:  [ 1 9 ~
F9:  [ 2 0 ~
F10: [ 2 1 ~
F11: [ 2 3 ~
F12: [ 2 4 ~
```

---

Reiterando, não sei se essa é a melhor forma, nem se é portável. Mas funcionou com sucesso nos meus testes no Windows 7 e Ubuntu.

Comment: Estou no Linux, mas agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: @FernandoGomes Eu meio que consegui uma solução pro Linux também, estou testando aqui no Vagrant pra ter certeza que funciona e em breve atualizo a resposta.

Comment: @FernandoGomes Pronto! Só tome cuidado pra não errar na hora de digitar o código, pois eu fiz isso e travei o meu terminal, precisei encerrar a sessão SSH "puxando a tomada" hehe. P.S. No futuro, aguarde um pouco mais antes de marcar uma resposta como aceita, vai que aparece alguém com uma resposta melhor... :)