# Como parar uma execução no Python?

Tags: python

Estou começando a programar em Python e gostaria de saber como faço para parar a execução do programa?

Na linguagem C por exemplo, existe o comando equivalente `system("pause")`. Se eu abrir o IDLE, mais especificamente o shell do Python o programa ao terminar a janela não fecha. Porém, se eu usar o executável do Python que é semelhante ao CMD o programa acaba se fechando ao terminar. O que faço para resolver esse problema?

Comment: `system("pause");` nao é um "comando do C" - ele usa uma chamada ao shell do sistema para rodar umoutro PROGRAMA inteiro - que é o Pause.  (O mesmo funciona em Python, como dado na resposta) - mas é equivalente a chamar um chaveiro pra arrombar a sua porta cada vez que quer entrar em casa, em vez de arrumar a fechadura.

Answer (score 5):

Use a função "input"  - ela aguarda até que o usuário digite enter (ele pode digitar mais texto antes de apertar enter, mas se você não for fazer nada com esse texto, é indiferente):

```
input("Pressione <enter> para continuar")
```

O `os.system("pause")` executa um outro programa inteiro - e significa que o programa "Pause" tem que existir no seu sistema operacional, e ele é algo só do Windows: seu programa Python (ou C) que funcionaria em Linux, Mac, Android, passa a ser "windows only" só por causa dele.
Mas sobretudo, usar `system("pause"), mesmo em C, é equivalente em programação, a chamar um guincho pra levar seu carro a algum lugar, com você dentro, por que o carro está sem gasolina, em vez de abastecer.

Já a função "input" é interna do Python, sequer precisa importar qualquer módulo - e depende apenas da interação do próprio runtime do Python com a entrada padrão do programa. (Em C o correto seria usar a função `fgets`).

Comment: >>>>>>>>>>>>>> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69853/3635

Comment: Isso. Mas algum demente começou a ensinar o tal `systen("pause")` para C em faculdades há algum tempo atrás, em vez de explicar qual era a natureza do terminal do stdin - as pessoas se formaram e hoje acham isso "normal". É uma das coisas mais surreais que já vi em computação.

Comment: Excelente explicação, poderia ter feito na pergunta que apontei ao invés de responder na dup e apontar nos campos de comentário.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta esse, ele vai esperar você digitar uma tecla para continuar

```
import os  
os.system("pause")
```

Comment: Funcionou, o código foi eficiente. Gostaria de agradecer pela ajuda e disponibilidade.